# How can I add an image to a WhatsApp message created from a click on my website through the API?

Tags: url, php, api

I want to send an image, text with product URL to WhatsApp from my website when the user clicks on the WhatsApp icon.

Currently I can send text with product URL but I don't know how to add a image parameter.

```
<li>
<a target="_blank" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=<?php echo h($photo->caption) ?><?php echo u(h($meta_url)) ?>">
   <i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
</li>
```

**output**

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=product-test-1http://localhost/test-1/show.html/product-1
```